# Global parameter in ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router

I'm using ui-router in AngularJS like this:

```
.state
('browse.category', {
      url: "/:category",
      templateUrl: "views/browseCategory.html",
      controller: function($stateParams, $scope) {
        $scope.params = $stateParams;
      }
    })
```

How can I make the `$stateParams` variable global so I can access it in any view / controller?

Right now I can only access the parameters in the nested view.

Comment: what do you mean by making it global? what's bad with inject it wherever you need it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [a working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/4pjoofCXq444kjXLqGx8?p=info), which uses this notation:

```
.run(['$rootScope', '$state', '$stateParams',
  function ($rootScope, $state, $stateParams) {
    $rootScope.$state = $state;
    $rootScope.$stateParams = $stateParams;
}])
```

And that makes it available anywhere:

```
<div >
  <h3>current state name: <var>{{$state.current.name}}</var></h3>


  <h5>params</h5>
  <pre>{{$stateParams | json}}</pre>
  <h5>state</h5>
  <pre>{{$state.current | json}}</pre>

</div>
```

Check it in action [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/4pjoofCXq444kjXLqGx8?p=info)

Answer (score 2):

$rootScope - global variable in angular.